# android list view image addition

Tags: android, android-layout

holder.text.setText(DATA[position]);
            holder.icon.setImageBitmap((position &1) == 1 ? mIcon1 : mIcon2);

```
        return convertView;
    }
```

How can I add more Images as this list view only displays 2 images. I see the above code only allows 2 images to be added in that order. I want to add more images.

Please help, thank you.

Comment: Your code seems to only display icon1 in the second row, on all other positions the icon2, right?

Answer (score 0):

Its simple..U can create
  ArrayList images=new ArrayList();

and add(Drawable img) to this arraylist by getting drawable by
Drawable img=getResources().getDrawabled(R.drawable.icon);

then set.. 
holder.icon.setImageDrawable(images.get(position));

or also use can use Integer array...and add images directly from res/drawable.
then array[position].